# Remove unstaged, uncommitted files in git when checking out a different branch

Tags: git, git-commit, unstage

I deleted both the local and remote branches for a particular branch

```
git branch -d branchName
git branch --delete --remotes origin/branchName
```

When I checkout out a different branch, I am still seeing the untracked/uncommitted files when I run `git status`.

Those files don't have any changes that I want to keep or stage or commit. I don't want to see them sitting in the area when I run `git status` on the different branch

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   ../../../../path/to/folder/file.html
    modified:   ../../../../path/to/folder/file.js
```

I want to see this when I run `git status` on any branch I checkout

```
On branch proj/branch/#
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/proj/branch/#'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Is there a way to do this, if so, how is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, to undo the changes on all files and restore them to their last commited state, you'd do :

```
git reset --hard
```

(here `HEAD` is implied)([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---hard))

**Warning** however : this is not undoable.

You could also just [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), this would also get rid of the changes, but in case you want to get them back later or just inspect them, you'll be able to, either with a simple `git stash show <stashRef>`, or with `git apply <stashRef>`, where the `<stashRef>` is to be found with `git stash list`.

---

To answer your comment about stash, in case you stashed something and don't need it any more, you have two ways of cleaning old stash entries :

```
# global
git stash clear

# or specific
git stash drop <entryRef>
```

(where `<entryRef>` is found through `git stash list`)

Comment: What if I don't ever want to unstash those modifications? (_they aren't needed at all_).

Comment: @Chris22 Then just go for the first method and reset to HEAD. **But** I'd like to have a dollar for each time I thought I wouldn't need something and regreted it later :-) A stash is not a big cost, and you can clear your whole stash list or specific entries at any time.